# Add 'selected' attribute using the option value

Tags: jquery, local-storage, drop-down-menu

I have a select box with 10 options. Each time you select an option it sets in the localstorage the value you selected with id "select1".

For example: If you select the first option you get in the localstorage: Key: Emailclient - Value: Option1.

Now, Iom trying to make the value of the localstorage, the selected attribute in the select form.

This is what I tried but doesn't seem to work:

```
if (localStorage.getItem("Select1") == "Option1"){ 
    $('#selectbox').val("Option1").attr("selected");
}
```

What I'm I doing wrong?

EDIT:

This is my code:

```
<select id="selectbox" >
                        <option>Default</option>
                        <option>Option 1</option>
                        <option>Option 3</option>
                        <option>Option 3</option>
                        <option>Option 4</option>
                        <option>Option 5</option>
                        <option>Option 6</option>
        </select>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This works:

```
var optionValue  = localStorage.getItem("Select1")
$("#selectbox").val(optionValue)
.find("option[value=" + optionValue +"]").attr('selected', true);
```

Comment: Friend, you save me (y).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (localStorage.getItem("Select1") == "Option1"){ 
    $('#selectbox option:contains(Option1)').prop('selected',true); // jquery 1.6+
}
```

if you are using a version of jQuery older than 1.6, replace `.prop` with `.attr`

Edit: more dynamic version

```
if (localStorage.getItem("Select1")) {
  $('#selectbox option:contains(' + localStorage.getItem("Select1") + ')').prop('selected',true);
}
```

Comment: it works for me, http://jsfiddle.net/uY7ck/2/ check your id's. you were selecing a select with an id of emailclient when the only select on the fiddle had an id of selectbox

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for something like this.  http://jsfiddle.net/tnPU8/3/

It loops through the options of the select box and compares their values with the values of `b`. If they are equal the index of the select box is changed so that the option that contains the value of `b` is displayed.

```
var b; //set equal to what you want to compare
$('#selectbox').find('option').each(function(i,e){
    console.log($(e).val());
    if($(e).val() == b){
        $('#selectbox').prop('selectedIndex',i);
    }
});
```

Edit: Using `localStorage` http://jsfiddle.net/tnPU8/7/

Comment: It doesn't work If im trying to retrieve from the localstorage. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/uY7ck

Comment: Thank you sir. I found my way to work better because of less code. Your way, I will need to type the If statement as many options I have. My way, is just 3 line of code. Thanks alot though

Answer (score 0):

On further review, it looks as though you wanted something more fully feature [link](http://jsfiddle.net/a6k7x/3/)

```
search = "Option 5";
$('#selectbox option:contains('+search+')').prop('selected',true);
```

Comment: It's not logical to work and it doesn't. You're setting the selectbox option to selected of what?

Comment: @Korvin you don't even need to navigate to the selected option. just call .val() on the select for the same result.

Comment: @Tentonaxe his original question was asking for the value of the selected option, not the contents of the selected option, otherwise you're completely correct.

Comment: @jQuerybeast your jsfiddle will not produce your desired outcome because you are referring to the wrong select box 0.0

Answer (score 0):

This is all you should need:

```
$("#selectbox").val(localStorage.getItem("selectbox"));
```

I've updated a previous fiddle for an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/uY7ck/1/

EDIT:
In the code you posted originally, assuming you are setting localStorage with the same select box, you would be comparing "Option1" (no space) with "Option 1" (space). That comparison will never work, so the option would never be selected.

Comment: On your edit: True. I found that to be a problem but anyways, all my options have no spaces. I found my way to work much better since I don't need to type the If statement as many times as my options, rather than only the 3 line code. Thanks alot though