# How to add "selected" in option attribute using Javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is code for select option and generate using php from database and i try to add `selected="selected"` to `value="4"` using jQuery or any javascript:

```
<select id="countryselect" name="country">
<option value="1">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="2">Albania</option>
<option value="3">Algeria</option>
<option value="4">Malaysia</option>
<option value="5">Maldives</option>
</select>
```

i try to refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473835/add-selected-attribute-using-the-option-value) but still can't .. below is my current script :

```
<script>
localStorage.setItem("Select1", "Malaysia");
    $('#countryselect').find('option').each(function(i,e){
        if($(e).val() == localStorage.getItem("Select1")){
            $('#countryselect').prop('selectedIndex',i);
        }
    });
</script>
```

thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`localStorage.getItem("Select1")` will return Malaysia and `$(e).val()` will return 1,2...5 in each loop. So your condition will never be true. Instead use

```
<script>
localStorage.setItem("Select1", "4");
    $('#countryselect').find('option').each(function(i,e){
        if($(e).val() == localStorage.getItem("Select1")){
            $('#countryselect').prop('selectedIndex',i);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 22):

The `selected` attribute is a [boolean attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.3.4.2), its presence sets the value of the related DOM property to `true`. If the attribute is absent, the value of the selected property is `false`.

If an option has the selected **attribute**, then when the page is first loaded, or the form the control is in is reset, that option will be the selected option.

If the option's selected **property** is set to `true`, then that option will be selected. However, if the form is reset, the default selected option will be selected (i.e. the one with the selected **attribute**, or the first option, or none).

To set the selected attribute (i.e. make the option the default selected option):

```
var select = document.getElementById('countryselect');
var option;

for (var i=0; i<select.options.length; i++) {
  option = select.options[i];

  if (option.value == '4') {
  // or
  // if (option.text == 'Malaysia') {
     option.setAttribute('selected', true);

     // For a single select, the job's done
     return; 
  } 
}
```

Note that this may not make the option the currently selected option, it will just add the selected attribute. To make sure it's selected (if that is what is required), the also set the selected property to `true` (see below).

Note that the second argument to [setAttribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-F68F082) is supposed to be a string that is used to set the attribute's value. However, the selected attribute doesn't have a "setable" value, so the second argument is ignored (e.g. even `false` will still set the attribute and make the option the default selected option). That causes some confusion. :-)

To set the selected property (i.e. just make the option the current selected option):

```
var select = document.getElementById('countryselect');
var option;

for (var i=0; i<select.options.length; i++) {
  option = select.options[i];

  if (option.value == '4') {
  // or
  // if (option.text == 'Malaysia') {
     option.selected = true;
     return;
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this super-clear explanation.  Much appreciated and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 16):

This should work simple, `$("#countryselect").val('4')​`

It will automatically set `selected=selected`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/muthkum/zYRkC/

Answer (score 7):

As of jQuery 1.6 "To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the .prop() method."

```
$("#countryselect option[value=4]").prop("selected", "selected")
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try

```
$("#countryselect").val('4')
    //OR

$("#countryselect option").val('4')​.attr("selected", true)​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/f5e8m/)

Comment: Do you mean `$("#countryselect option[value=4]").attr("selected", true)`?

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#countryselect > option[value *= "4"] ').attr('selected',true);
```

this will work