# How to pre select an option from dropdown menu in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, directory-listing

I'm working on a WordPress theme for a listing directory, and I'm trying to pre select an option from a dropdown menu so that when someone opens that page they will get the listings from that option right away.

I tried with jQuery but it didn't work so I'm stuck here right now. Any help is welcome.

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4L29U.jpg

EDIT: I found a fix, I made "Producer" the only option, and changed the if statement from !empty($term_ID) to empty($term_ID).

It might not be the best solution but it works for me. Thanks everyone.

```
<select data-placeholder="<?php echo esc_html__('Select Category','dwt- 
listing');?>" name="l_category" class="allow_clear" id="l_category">

<option value=""><?php echo esc_html__('Select an 
option','dwt-listing'); ?>
</option>

<option value="all"><?php echo esc_html__('All Categories','dwt- 
listing'); ?>
<?php

        //selective
        if( isset( $_GET['l_category'] ) && $_GET['l_category'] != "" )
        {
            $term_ID = $_GET['l_category'];
        }
        foreach( $listing_cats as $cats )
        {
        ?>  
          <option <?php if ($cats->term_id == $term_ID) { ?>selected="selected"<?php } ?> value="<?php echo esc_attr( $cats->term_id ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $cats->name ); ?></option>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
       </select>
```

Comment: Does this code set the correct option as selected in the dropdown?

Comment: This code is for the default placeholder "Select Category". I'm trying to set the "Producer" option as default.

Answer (score 0):

This example could help

```
var select = document.getElementById('countryselect');
var option;

for (var i=0, i<select.options.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  option = select.options[i];

  if (option.value == '4') {
  // or
  // if (option.text = 'Malaysia') {
     option.setAttribute('selected', true);

     // For a single select, the job's done
     return; 
  }  
}
```

Here is the link
[How to add "selected" in option attribute using Javascript or jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557999/how-to-add-selected-in-option-attribute-using-javascript-or-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

```
I have made a little change in your code.
check this and first in sure that you have got $term_ID or not because your selected option depend on this variable.

Replace this:-

    <option <?php if ($cats->term_id == $term_ID) { ?>selected="selected"<?php } ?> value="<?php echo esc_attr( $cats->term_id ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $cats->name ); ?></option> 

With this:-

    <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $cats->term_id ); ?>" <?php if ($cats->term_id==$term_ID) { echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> ><?php echo esc_html( $cats->name ); ?></option>
```