# How to set an option with a specific title attribute as the selected item in Angular using Bootstrap's selectpicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, bootstrap-selectpicker

Some of the options may have the same value, so I can not select the right option by `setValue(...)` so I was tring use the `'selected'` but it didn't work.

I tried this, but it didn't work.

```
$('#my-select').find('option[title="2"]').prop('selected', true);
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
```

Answer (score 1):

In Angular you should avoid use jQuery to change a value. You should use two-binding way. Angular is based to relationate variables in .ts with values in the .html (Believe me, it's the most important concept you should to have in mind)

In this case is so easy to use [[(ngModel)]](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#using-ngmodel-on-a-standalone-control)

```
<select [(ngModel)]="variable" ...>
    ...
</select>
```

And in .ts

```
variable="2"
```

Comment: it's an old project,like 4or5 years ago.  So i have to use jQuery :(  . And the problem is that the project is too complicated, I can't simply change the value of the option to distinguish them, because it will involve too many effects.  So i decided to set the selected option by its own title attribute. And it didn't work :(

Comment: And more detail, the select is in the formgroup.  So I use 'setValue' to set the select's value.  and since the options may have same value, i decided to add the 'selected' attribut to make the real option selected. but didn;t work

Comment: Check the answer in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473835/add-selected-attribute-using-the-option-value), for jQuery older than 1.6, replace .prop with .attr. NOTE: really I don't know what do you want to say with "setValue", I imagine you can use `(document.getElementById('my-select') as any).value="2"` or `$('#my-select').value="2"`.